# WCF Service Modify Return Object Properties Impact

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I wish to modify a WCF service that is used by multiple Azure Sites. A specific method returns a JobInformation object with various properties such as Name, Description, OrderDate etc. 
What impact would there be if i changed the JobInformation object to include an extra field, DespatchDate.

Would the existing sites that use the service complain as they already have model definition for the return JobInformation that contains fewer properties than the return value they receive or would they ignore the extra fields? These methods are called via a Service Bus if that makes any difference.

Apologies in advance if i am missing key information as i am new to WCF.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are better off testing it in a test app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What impact would there be if i changed the JobInformation object to include an extra field, DespatchDate.

The existing sites will work fine if you add additional fields to JobInformation. The new fields will not be viewed in your existing sites if you don't update the service reference.

If you debug your website, you can see the additional fields by ExtensionData property.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advice, just what i was looking for. Also never knew about the ExtensionData so that really helps too.

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment and the solution. I have since tried this out on my test environment and can confirm that it had no impact on the test Azure site.